# Openstreetmap vector layer vs google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, openlayers

I am adding Vector layer to my openstreetmap which works fine

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("GML", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                    url: "gml/polygon.xml",
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GML()
            })
            });
```

How can I do same in google maps (without using openlayers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768054/how-to-use-gml-or-shp-files-on-google-maps-api-v3) is the (almost) same question with an answer, provided you use API V3, but without using any API code or openLayers... I doubt it, because you need to add an external layer for this...